# jQuery - Onclick open link in jQuery pop

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Im looking for a jQuery login that will target specific links (based on class) and will open that link in a popup window?

So instead of having to leave the site they get all external content served in a pop-up.

Does anyone know of such a plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need jQuery for this. You can do something like this:

**HTML**:

```
<a href="http://www.example.com" onClick="window.open(this.href, null, ' '); return false;">Click me!</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

View this sample : http://jsfiddle.net/Davood/MF44t/

or you can colorbox plugin : http://colorpowered.com/colorbox/

see this page for demo : http://colorpowered.com/colorbox/core/example1/index.html

and click on " Outside HTML (Ajax) " link to see demo .

Comment: Was looking for something a little fancier, some kind of lightbox effect?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I got you correctly, but I guess this could do the trick
(I'm not sure I really understood what you want to get)

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="jquery-1.5.js"></script>
        <script>
         $(
            function() {
                $(".classSpecialLink").each(
                    function() {
                        this.goto = this.href;
                        this.href = "javascript:;";
                    }
                ).click(
                    function() {
                        window.open(this.goto);
                    }
                )
            }
        ); 
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a href="http://www.google.com" class="classNormalLink">normal link</a><br />
        <a href="http://www.google.com" class="classSpecialLink">special link</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

ps: by login did you mean plugin?